# iOS Google Plus integration and sharing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-plus

I am trying to share content from my app to Google Plus. To this end, I have used the following code:

```
-(IBAction)handleGPlus{

    id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

    [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dummy.com"]];
    [shareBuilder setTitle:@"Some title" description:@"Some description" thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dummy.com/image"]];
    [shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:kClientId];
    [shareBuilder open];
}
```

And I have set up the clientID like so:

```
static NSString * const kClientId = @"MY_CLIENT_ID";
```

But I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You must specify |clientID| for |GPPSignIn|'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x346932a3 0x3c33897f 0x346931c5 0x1d2e33 0x122725 0x365860c5 0x36586077 0x36586055 0x3658590b  0x36585e01 0x364ae5f1 0x3649b801 0x3649b11b 0x3819e5a3 0x3819e1d3 0x34668173 0x34668117 0x34666f99 0x345d9ebd 0x345d9d49 0x3819d2eb 0x364ef301 0xee20d 0xed600)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I have included the `GoogleOpenSource.Framework` and `GooglePlus.Framework` files too.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because you are not assigning client_ id of GPPSignIn class

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you are not assigning client_ id of GPPSignIn class. Try this code in your appdelegate

```
    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"MY_CLIENT_ID";
    [GPPDeepLink setDelegate:self];
    [GPPDeepLink readDeepLinkAfterInstall];
```

then try [sharing link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share) for implementing it in right way.

I hope it helps you.