# How to get user information in Google plus integration with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, google-plus

Hi I am integrating google plus integration I want to fetch user information who is currently login. I am able to get token after login but I don't know how to get personal information.
I am login step by step as following this is only because I want to get login without open external browser.

Open url link in `UIWebView` which open login screen in View Did Load.

```
UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
webView.tag=99;
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&data-requestvisibleactions=%@",[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID,callbakc,scope,visibleactions];


[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Get call for token Login

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
 if ([[[request URL] host] isEqualToString:@"localhost"]) {

        // Extract oauth_verifier from URL query
        NSString* verifier = nil;
        NSArray* urlParams = [[[request URL] query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        for (NSString* param in urlParams) {
            NSArray* keyValue = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            NSString* key = [keyValue objectAtIndex:0];
            if ([key isEqualToString:@"code"]) {
                verifier = [keyValue objectAtIndex:1];
                NSLog(@"verifier %@",verifier);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (verifier) {

            NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"code=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&redirect_uri=%@&grant_type=authorization_code", verifier,[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID,secret,callbakc];
            NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setHTTPBody:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
            receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

        } else {
            // ERROR!
        }

        [webView removeFromSuperview];

        return NO;
    }
```

and I get the response in did recieve data

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
[receivedData appendData:data];
NSLog(@"verifier %@",receivedData);}
```

Now after token I want to call for fetch user information who is login, Kindly guide me on this how can I achieve this target, this will be great for me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look this answer for [ios-google-plus-integration][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833632/ios-google-plus-integration-and-sharing/16833773#16833773

Comment: @user3874146 have you got solution? please let me know .. I have same issue.